# Is there a better way to write a LINQ function?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-2.1

So, I am new to LINQ and trying to figure out how to filter items.
That’s my task

```
public async Task<PagedList<Item>> GetItems (ItemParams itemParams) {
    var items = _context.Items.AsQueryable ();
    if (itemParams.CategoryId > 0) {
        var category = GetCategory (itemParams.CategoryId);

        items = items.Where (i => FilterItems (i, category.Result));

    }
    return await PagedList<Item>.CreatAsync (items, itemParams.PageNumber, itemParams.PageSize);
}
```

and the function that decides which items to return is

```
static bool FilterItems (Item item, Category category) {

    if (item.CategoryId == category.Id) {
        return true;
    }
    if (category.Children.Count > 0) {
        foreach (Category cat in category.Children) {
          return  FilterItems (item, cat);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

the get category func

```
    public async Task<Category> GetCategory (int? id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        }
        var categories = _context.Categories.Include (x => x.Children).AsEnumerable ().Where (c => c.Id == id);
        categories = Traverse (categories);
        var category = await Task.FromResult (categories.First (c => c.Id == id));
        return category;
    }
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter will not work as expected, as the `foreach` returns at the first loop. Also the name `FilterItems` is not intuitive.

```
static bool ContainsItem(Category category, Item item)
{
    return
        category.Id == item.CategoryId ||
        category.Children.Any(c => ContainsItem(c, item);
}
```

Since C# performs a short-circuit evaluation of the [|| Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator), the second term will not be evaluated if the first matches. Note that this is not a dirty trick, but is part of the C# specification.

Comment: now i am getting this error Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'where ContainsCategory([i], __category_Result_0)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally

Comment: If you are querying an EF or EF-Core or other `IQueryable` source, then you cannot call your user defined functions. The LINQ query will be translated to SQL, and your function is unknown to SQL! This recursive approach only works with LINQ-to-Objects!.

Comment: after adding the async key befor get category all works fine thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the code, it seems `FilterItems()` returns true if item is in current category or any sub-categories?

If that's the case, I think your current code has a problem: the recursive call to `FilterItems()` returns result immediately for the first sub-category without checking other sub-categories

Here is the modified code:

```
public static bool InCategoryOrSubCategory(Item item, Category category)
{
    return item.CategoryId == category.Id ||
        category.Children.Any(subCategory => InCategoryOrSubCategory(item, subCategory));
}
```

I change the name to `InCategoryOrSubCategory` to make it clearer

Here's a curried version, to make the `Where` call slightly nicer (but the method itself is a bit more cryptic):

```
public static Func<Item, bool> InCategoryOrSubCategory(Category category) 
{
    return item => 
        item.CategoryId == category.Id || 
        category.Children.Any(subCategory => InCategoryOrSubCategory(subCategory)(item));
}
```

Usage:

```
items.Where(InCategoryOrSubCategory(category))
```

Comment: when i tried your method i am getting this error cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Application.API.Models.Category>' to 'Application.API.Models.Category'

Comment: @HassanKalach it seems your `GetCategory()` is an `async` method? You need to do an `await GetCategory()` to get actual Category instead of `Task<Category>`

Comment: yes sorry i added the await befor getCategory but the error is , Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Application.API.Models.Item>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Application.API.Models.Item>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) [Application.API]

Comment: @HassanKalach hmm, without much details on where that error appears, my guess is that it appears at `CreateAsync`? The `Where` call will return an `IEnumerable` and you will need to see the signature of the `CreateAsync` and adapt to it somehow, e.g. using `AsQueryable` on the result of `Where`

Comment: i added the getCategory function

Comment: the curried version is not working the first version works fine